# Week of quarter calculation SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, amazon-redshift

I am trying to find the week of quarter from a cal_date_d table using sql. My table has cal_date, fiscal quarter start and end date. I also have a column which has the fiscal_week_of_year. and my fiscal year starts from feb.
However the closest query i've got to resolve this issue is below:

```
select datepart(week, DATEADD(MONTH,-10,cal_date)) - ((DatePart(quarter, DATEADD(MONTH,-10,cal_date))-1) *13), 
       fiscal_week_of_year,
       weekofqtr,
       cal_date
  from cal_date_d_tst
```

Now the first week result i am always getting is 0. I am not sure where I am going wrong.

help me out on this one..

[image: Description]

Comment: what should be the expected data according to your sample set?

Comment: @BhupeshC it should always start the week of quarter count on first sunday of the fiscal year

Answer (score 0):

If you have `fiscal_quarter_start`, then doesn't this work?

```
select 1 + datediff(day, fiscal_quarter_start, cal_date) / 7
```

This just calculates the number of days into the quarter and divides by 7.

Comment: @gordanlinoff unfortunately this is not helping.. Whats happening is the week should always start from sunday and ends at saturday. in the above case, if the quarter is starting from wednesday, query is considering the wed-tue as the week.

Answer (score 0):

If you base your query on DATEPART(Quarters) use the following.

```
DATEDIFF(WEEK, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, '2012-03-17'), 0), '2012-03-17') +1 AS WeekNoMonth,DATEDIFF(WEEK, DATEADD(QUARTER, DATEDIFF(QUARTER, 0, '2012-03-17'), 0), '2012-03-17') +1
```

[Source](http://gopika-lasitha.blogspot.com/2012/06/get-week-numbers-for-quarter-and-month.html)